# react-bootstrap-multiselect not working

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-multiselect

I must be doing something really stupid cause I cant get react-bootstrap-multiselect to work.

```
import { MultiSelect } from 'react-bootstrap-multiselect'

export class StatusBar extends Component {  

@observable status = {}

  list = [{ value: 'One', selected: true }, { value: 'Two' }, { value: 'Three' }, { value: 'Four', label: 'Four Label' }]

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.store = this.props.store
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className='statusBar'>
        <div className='item'>
          <span><MultiSelect data={this.list} multiple /></span>
        </div>
        <div className='item'>
          <span>John Doe</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )

  }
}
```

I get the error: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string

I also debugged bootstrap-multiselect.js and noticed that the value ko is undefined and therefore skipping most of the code.

```
    if (typeof ko !== 'undefined' && ko.bindingHandlers && !ko.bindingHandlers.multiselect) {
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a semicolon to the end of your list property - do you still have an error then?

Comment: no luck :( thanks anyway